# actor abstraction in Ray

Tags: distributed-computing, actor, dask-distributed, ray

When learning the Ray technology for the distributed Python, I read the following statement on Ray, and I am not fully understanding what does it really mean? Any explanations with some application context is appreciated.

[Actors: An important part of the Ray API is the actor abstraction for sharing mutable state between tasks
(e.g., the state of a neural network or the state of a simulator). This blends very nicely with the side-effect
free dataflow abstraction and is important for our workloads both to share state and to avoid expensive
initializations. I don't think there is an analogue in Dask.](https://github.com/ray-project)

Comment: In Ray, Actors can store objects that can be queried from other tasks. Imagine you define a variable at Actor's instantiation (through `__init__`). Say this variable is global and mutable in the sense that tasks can access it and modify it. As Actors can only execute one method at a time, you can safely query the value of your variable or even change it without a race condition taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are writing distributed applications. The most common workflow is to use "side-effect-free" tasks and run them concurrently. Let's call it "stateless" workflow. It means running those tasks won't change any states of your applications. Ray has abstraction for this sort of things (called tasks).

```
# Ray task abstraction
@ray.remote
def f():
    return True
```

But sometimes, you want to have "states". For example, imagine you run distributed reinforcement learning applications. You might want to have shared states for your simulator that tasks can access. Ray's actor APIs are used to support this type of "stateful" workflow.

Simply put, Ray actors are just Python classes that are instantiated in one of machines in your cluster. You can use actor APIs to allow your tasks to access methods of actors.